# How to point buildspec away from root

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

currently my CodeBuild works. I have my buildspec in my root directly and it successfully builds. I am looking to move the buildspec.

Current structure

```
buildspec.yml
net-core
-> net-core-api
```

Proposed new location

```
net-core
-> net-core-api 
   -> buildspec.yml
```

When I updated the project to point to the new location, I get the following error

```
[Container] 2023/08/28 18:14:26 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src2839811517/src
[Container] 2023/08/28 18:14:26 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
[Container] 2023/08/28 18:14:26 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: stat /codebuild/output/src2839811517/src/net-core/net-core-api/buildspec.yml: no such file or directory
```

I've tried setting to look at these paths

1. net-core/net-core-api/buildspec.yml
2. ./net-core/net-core-api/buildspec.yml
3. /net-core/net-core-api/buildspec.yml

and unfortunately those didn't work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html), to override the default buildspec location you must do one of the following:

> - Run the AWS CLI create-project or update-project command, setting the buildspec value to the path to the alternate buildspec file relative to the value of the built-in environment variable CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR. You can also do the equivalent with the create project operation in the AWS SDKs. For more information, see Create a build project or Change a build project's settings.

> - Run the AWS CLI start-build command, setting the buildspecOverride value to the path to the alternate buildspec file relative to the value of the built-in environment variable CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR. You can also do the equivalent with the start build operation in the AWS SDKs. For more information, see Run a build.

> - In an AWS CloudFormation template, set the BuildSpec property of Source in a resource of type AWS::CodeBuild::Project to the path to the alternate buildspec file relative to the value of the built-in environment variable CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR. For more information, see the BuildSpec property in AWS CodeBuild project source in the AWS CloudFormation User Guide.